# aws-cdk rename S3 bucket?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-cdk-context

I'm new to aws-cdk but was curious if it is possible to rename a bucket once it's created so it doesn't have the naming format of ?

I've tried this logic

```
const core = require(`@aws-cdk/core`);
const s3 = require(`@aws-cdk/aws-s3`);




class s3Build extends core.Construct {
    constructor(scope, id) {
        super(scope, id) 
        const bucketName = process.env.s3Bucket + `-` + process.env.environment
        console.log(bucketName);

            const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, bucketName);

            const bucketNameOutput = new s3.CfnBucket(this, `NewName`, {

            });

            bucketNameOutput.overrideLogicalId(`myBucketsNewName`)
           
    }
}



module.exports = {s3Build}
```

When I run the above logic it does rename the bucket in a sense, but it still retains the original name.  Below is the new output:

```
<stack-name>myBucketsNewName<alpha-numeric-number>
```

The only thing that changed was the bucket name but it still shows the stack name and the alpha-numeric-number.

Looking at the documentation below it seems I have the right method `overrideLogicalId` but not getting the output I'm desiring.  What I want is to just have the bucket name be `myBucketsNewName` and not have the stack name and the alpha numeric number.

Am I missing something?

Comment: We cannot change S3 bucket name once created. If you do, create a new bucket and move everything. Is `overrideLogicalId` you're mentioning for changing logicalid in cloudformation?

Answer (score 2):

the 'id' - that is the string right after the this/self variable in a cdk construct function, refers to the LogicalID of the resource. The LogicalIDs are what CloudFormation uses to identify a given sub section of at template as a particular resource, and link that sub section to that resource for future updates to your stack.

CDK does NOT recommend you set your own names, but as pointed out the bucketName attribute is available. The reason this is not recommended is because it takes away from some of the power of CDK - which is the ability to redeploy your entire stack in multiple accounts, environments, or even just again in the same account to try a few different things. Since resource names have to be unique per service in an account (and S3 names are GLOBALLY unique!) then by setting a name, you cannot recreate this stack somewhere else without first deleting the old bucket or changing the name.

if you are going to set your buckets name, I highly recomend setting a removalPolicy attribute as well, so the CDK stacks can delete the bucket if its removed from your stack.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to resolve the roadblock by using the below prop values.

```
const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, bucketName, {
                bucketName: `myBucketsNewName`
            })
```

When I added that bucketName property value and deployed via the cdk the bucket was renamed to what I put in the bucketName field.

Comment: FYI - S3 buckets cannot be renamed. What this did is to remove the old bucket from the stack (while retaining it by default) and create a new empty bucket with the specified name.